# Can I define the minimum number of executer threads always kept alive for an embedded tomcat 8?

Tags: java, performance, spring-boot, threadpool, embedded-tomcat-8

My tomcat server creates one executor thread per request until it gets to 10 executor threads (after the first 10 requests).

[image: Executer thread after 1 request]
[image: Executer threads after 10 requests]

Is there any way I can customize this in order to start the 10 executors at the same time?

The main goal is to minimise the response time

Thank you in advance,

Abel

PD: I'm using embedded Tomcat 8.0.15 and SpringBoot

Comment: There is a `minSpareThreads` attribute you can include in `<Connector..` in your server.xml file, but i don't think that necessarily means it will start them as soon as the server starts up.  Startup for each thread shouldn't be a big issue, are you having problems with it spinning them up from cold?

Comment: I'm using SpringBoot and all my configuration is from Java. I saw that attribute in the doc (https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/config/executor.html) but no idea how to set it from SpringBoot

Comment: Ah, apologies, i am not familiar with SpringBoot